# Thymeleaf switch case on integer

Tags: java, integer, switch-statement, thymeleaf

I've been looking for documentation on Thymeleaf's 'new' switch case but either I'm looking in the wrong places, or there isn't too much of it.
Anyhow, here's my issue:

```
<div th:switch="${profileModel.goal}">
    <p th:case="*">No goal specified</p>
    <p th:case="1">Lose weight</p>
    <p th:case="2">Gain muscle</p>
    <p th:case="3">Overall fit</p>
</div>
```

Now I know for a fact that `${profileModel.goal}` is either 1, 2 or 3. I checked by simply printing the value in a paragraph above it, but the printed message is always 'No goal specified'.

Is it not possible to switch over integers or am I going to have a facepalm moment soon?

Comment: What is the problem you see? Are you getting an error, or is it always matching the first case? Or is it doing nothing?

Comment: Did you try char 1 inside double quotes like "'1'"

Comment: I have Ankit, same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your default case should be at the end, not the beginning.

Comment: Called it! *facepalm*